# Why is my custom link formula field reference returning the value of the wrong field, when the referenced field is blank?

Tags: formula, custom-link

I want to use the value of the account custom text field named `Id__c`, in a custom link on the account object. I want the custom link to go to two different pages depending on if there's a value in the `Id__c` field or not.

My formula looks like this:

```
{!IF(
    ISBLANK( Account.Id__c ),
    URLFOR("http://isBlank.com", null),
    URLFOR("http://isNotBlank.com/" & Account.Id__c, null)
)}


/* I'm using the URLFOR() function in order for the URL returned by the function to be properly encoded */
```

If the `Id__c` field is blank, I would expect the link to go to http://isBlank.com, however upon testing:

- If the `Account.Id__c` field is blank, the link goes to
  http://isNotBlank.com/001m000001Fc4xR.
- If the `Account.Id__c` field
  has the value "12345", the link goes to http://isNotBlank.com/12345.

As you can see, the ISBLANK() function is always returning false, since if the 'Account.Id__c' field value is actually blank, the function appears to be evaluating the 'Account.Id' value instead, which can never be blank. Either way, it's always evaluating a non-blank value.

I simplified the formula for testing, to just the following:

```
http://example.com/{!Account.Id__c}
```

- If the `Account.Id__c` field is blank, the link goes to http://example.com/001m000001Fc4xR.
- If the `Account.Id__c` field has the value "12345" the link goes to http://example.com/12345.

Is this is a bug? How can I workaround this issue to effectively test for a blank value in my `Id__c` field?

Here's some screenshots showing the issue:
[image: Custom link formula]
[image: Showing the value of Id__c is blank]
[image: Link going to the ID of the record]
I verified that the field is actually blank using Salesforce Inspector.
[image: Salesforce Inspector showing the value of Id__c is truly blank]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to figure out why the `Id__c` reference was incorrectly returning the record `Id`, but I ended up just handling this eventuality in my formula, assuming that the if `Id__c` was equal to `Id`, then it's blank.

My resultant formula was something like:

```
{!IF(
    Account.Id__c = Account.Id || ISBLANK( Account.Id__c ),
    URLFOR("http://isBlank.com", null),
    URLFOR("http://isNotBlank.com/" & Account.Id__c, null)
)}
```